# Thread state on blocking Stream.Read() call

Tags: c#, multithreading

If the "blocking" `Stream.Read()` method is called inside a thread (e.g. from the ThreadPool) what exactly "happens" to the thread / the thread state?

What exactly does blocking in the sense of the `Stream.Read()` method mean? I know it's blocking the further code execution until data is available, but does it also block the thread or will / can it be released to the thread pool after the call, similar to what Stephen Cleary explains in his [blog-post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) (although it's no async method), or uses it some sort of busy waiting mechanism under the hood which prevents the release of the thread?

Comment: Blocking is  associated with syncronous methods, it means current thread continues execution only after `Stream.Read()` returns result.  
  Non-blocking, as opposite, associated with immediate continuation after method call, and what Stephen Cleary's blog is about.

Comment: Yes, it will block the thread. That's what blocking is.

Comment: It does depend somewhat on the concrete Stream class.  But most typically the framework will pinvoke ReadFile().  Which makes the OS put the thread in a wait state, ProcessThread.ThreadState == Wait and not scheduling it for execution anymore, until the driver has completed the I/O request.